# Multiple checkbox filtering with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filtering

I am playing around and trying to create a funzies website that will list recipes depending on what ingredients you check off.  For example, if i have a recipe that requires beef, apples and kale i dont want it to show up in the results until all 3 ingredients have been checked.

Currently my script will return all results that have at least one of the checked ingredients.

Here is the relevant part of the html

```
                    <h4>Meat</h4>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="bacon" id="bacon" /> Bacon
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="beef" id="beef" /> Beef
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="chicken" id="chicken" /> Chicken
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="dove" id="dove" /> Dove
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="ham" id="ham" /> Ham
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="pork" id="pork" /> Pork
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="quail" id="quail" /> Quail
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="salmon" id="salmon" /> Salmon
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="sausage" id="sausage" /> Sausage
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="scallops" id="scallops" /> Scallops
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="shrimp" id="shrimp" /> Shrimp
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="tilapia" id="tilapia" /> Tilapia
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="trout" id="trout" /> Trout
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="tuna" id="tuna" /> Tuna
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" rel="turkey" id="turkey" /> Turkey
                    </label>

                    <!-- checkboxes for vegetable type -->
                <h4>Vegetables</h4>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="arugula" id="arugula" /> Arugula
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="broccolini" id="broccolini" /> Broccolini
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="cabbage" id="cabbage" /> Cabbage
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="celery" id="celery" /> Celery
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="collardGreens" id="collardGreens" /> Collard Greens
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="dill" id="dill" /> Dill
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="kale" id="kale" /> Kale
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="lettuce" id="lettuce" /> Lettuce
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="peas" id="peas" /> Peas
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="vegetables" rel="spinach" id="spinach" /> Spinach
                    </label>

              <!-- checkboxes for fruit type -->
                <h4>Fruit</h4>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="apple" id="apple" /> Apple
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="avocado" id="avocado" /> Avocado
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="banana" id="banana" /> Banana
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="blackberry" id="blackberry" /> Blackberry
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="blueberry" id="blueberry" /> Blueberry
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="cherry" id="cherry" /> Cherry
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="coconut" id="coconut" /> Coconut
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="cranberry" id="cranberry" /> Cranberry
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="grape" id="grape" /> Grape
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="raisin" id="raisin" /> Raisin
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="grapefruit" id="grapefruit" /> Grapefruit
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="lemon" id="lemon" /> Lemon
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="lime" id="lime" /> Lime
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="mango" id="mango" /> Mango
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="cantaloupe" id="cantaloupe" /> Cantaloupe
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="honeydew" id="honeydew" /> Honeydew
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="watermelon" id="watermelon" /> Watermelon
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="nectarine" id="nectarine" /> Nectarine
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="olive" id="olive" /> Olive
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="orange" id="orange" /> Orange
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="papaya" id="papaya" /> Papaya
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="peach" id="peach" /> Peach
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="pear" id="pear" /> Pear
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="plum" id="plum" /> Plum
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="prune" id="prune" /> Prune
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="pineapple" id="pineapple" /> Pineapple
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="pomegranate" id="pomegranate" /> Pomegranate
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="raspberry" id="raspberry" /> Raspberry
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="strawberry" id="strawberry" /> Strawberry
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" rel="tomato" id="tomato" /> Tomato
                    </label>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">  

            <ul class="results">
                <li class="dinner bacon kale apple">Steak and Salad</li>
                <li class="dinner">Result 2</li>
                <li class="apple">Result 3</li>
                <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

and here is the current script i am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.results > li').hide();

        $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
            $('.results > li').hide();
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to use Events and EventListeners.

Add an EventListener to some wrapper div element that will update on an 'onClick' event: since Events 'bubble up' the DOM, if any nested input element is clicked  within that wrapper div (an ingredient, for your purposes) the onClick event will 'bubble up' and then be handled by the containing div's EventListener.  The nifty thing is that the Event will contain information about its source (a property called target: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which is what DOM element generated the event)...we'll use this fact later.

In addition to the Event, have an object that has properties the names of your ingredients and values of true/false (indicating whether or not the user has selected that ingredient).  Then, use the id of the Event's target (which you've set up as the ingredients name) as your index for the object.

You can then use the object to see which recipes can be used with the given recipes (one way is to have each recipe have an array of ingredients, as I did).

Code:

```
//just here for visualization purposes
var results = document.getElementById('results');
var canMakeDish = document.getElementById('canMakeDish');

var options = document.getElementById('options');

//object that keeps track of what the user has selected so far
var selected = {
  bacon: false,
  beef: false,
  chicken: false,
  dove: false,
  ham: false,
  // and so on and so forth...
};


//an example recipe's requirements
var dishRequirements = ['bacon', 'beef', 'peas', 'mango'];

options.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    //prevent the Event from travelling up the DOM
    event.stopPropagation();
  //update our selected object with whatever the status of the clicked element was
  selected[event.target.id] = event.target.checked;
  //simply adds the id of the input element to the results for visualization of what is being affected
  results.innerHTML = 'You just modified ' + event.target.id;
  //Do your updating of results here
  var dishValid = true;
  dishRequirements.forEach((val) => {
    if (!selected[val]) {
      dishValid = false;
    }
  });

  if (dishValid) {
    canMakeDish.innerHTML = "You can make the dish!"
  } else {
    canMakeDish.innerHTML = "You can't make the dish :(";
  }

});
```

JSFiddle for working example (the spacing of the checkboxes is a little wonky, so make sure you're selecting the right ingredients): https://jsfiddle.net/rtq92oyf/2

Forgive me if my explanation is a bit rough...I just got off a long shift and I'm a little tired.  I'd be happy to explain more another time if you'd like!